# Using multiple yields in Ember to display header, body, footer in different places

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

How to use multiple yields in Ember to display header, body, footer in different places? Added below a sample code for reference. But not working and throws the error saying,

> Assertion Failed: A helper named "ib.footer" could not be found

**components/common/info-bar-footer.hbs:**

```
{{yield}}
```

**components/common/info-bar-header.hbs:**

```
{{yield}}
```

**components/common/info-bar.hbs:**

```
<div class="info-bar" style="display: {{if isopen 'block' 'none'}}">
    <div class="info-bar-header">
        <button class="btn-close" data-dismiss="info-bar" {{action "handleCloseInfoBar"}}>x</button>
        {{yield (hash header=(component "common/info-bar-header"))}}
    </div>
    <div class="info-bar-footer">
        {{yield (hash footer=(component "common/info-bar-footer"))}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**templates/home.hbs:**

```
{{#common/info-bar isopen=true as |ib|}}
    {{#ib.header}}
        <p class="info-content">
            Hello, nice to see you again
        </p>
    {{/ib.header}}
    {{#ib.footer}}
        <button class="btn-default">Ok</button>
    {{/ib.footer}}
{{/common/info-bar}}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for Named Blocks: https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0226-named-blocks.md It's in implementation: https://www.emberjs.com/statusboard/

Comment: So isn't possible to use named blocks now? If yes, are there any other workarounds to get the expected output?

Comment: @feanor07 Provided one of the possible work-a-rounds until named block land. IMO it's the best one. https://github.com/ciena-blueplanet/ember-block-slots isn't well maintained anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Let me explain why you are getting error and how to solve it. You have the following template:

```
{{#common/info-bar isopen=true as |ib|}}
    {{#ib.header}}
        <p class="info-content">
            Hello, nice to see you again
        </p>
    {{/ib.header}}
    {{#ib.footer}}
        <button class="btn-default">Ok</button>
    {{/ib.footer}}
{{/common/info-bar}}
```

When this piece of code is run; the code block you provided in between `#common/info-bar - /common/info-bar` will be tried to be run for every piece of `yield` within the `common/info-bar` component. So for the first `yield`; `common/info-bar` yields the following json object which you named as `ib` in your block form usage: `{ header:(component "common/info-bar-header") }`. That means; the execution of your block for the first `yield` has an `ib` object that simply does not contain any `footer` property. So; when you try to render the footer component with `ib.footer`; an error is raised which indicates `ib.footer` is not defined.

In order to fix that, you can `yield` additional properties to identify individual `yield`s within `common/info-bar`. Let the code talk:

```
<div class="info-bar" style="display: {{if isopen 'block' 'none'}}">
    <div class="info-bar-header">
        <button class="btn-close" data-dismiss="info-bar" {{action "handleCloseInfoBar"}}>x</button>
        {{yield (hash header=(component "common/info-bar-header") isHeader=true)}}
    </div>
    <div class="info-bar-footer">
        {{yield (hash footer=(component "common/info-bar-footer") isFooter=true)}}
    </div>
</div>
```

now you can use these markers within `home.hbs` and perform condition checks as:

```
{{#common/info-bar isopen=true as |ib|}}
    {{#if ib.isHeader}}
        {{#ib.header}}
            <p class="info-content">
                Hello, nice to see you again
            </p>
        {{/ib.header}}
    {{/if}}
    {{#if ib.isFooter}}
        {{#ib.footer}}
            <button class="btn-default">Ok</button>
        {{/ib.footer}}
    {{/if}}
{{/common/info-bar}}
```

Those `if` checks within the code block will make sure that; you are placing the correct content to the correct `yield` place. I hope this clarifies the issue for you.